# Drupal remove/delete all pages that contain a certain word in the content

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I have inherited a Drupal website that has been plagued with spam content, I am wanting to hunt all pages/content down that includes a keyword and delete them, is this possible within Drupal or would I need to delete the content via mysql? And if so how would I go about this, I am pretty new to the Drupal infrastructure.

Comment: Which version of Drupal is your website using?

Comment: it's drupal 7.59

Comment: You need to know which content type(s) and which field(s) are involved. Basically, drupal content is materialized as an entity, usually a node, for which some fields are "attached" depending on the node type. Now, the 1st thing is to know how the spam landed in database (in order to know "where" it is stored). It could come from a form submission probably, in this case which form, and in which kind of input field? how such form is built/managed (using drupal form api or not) ? You can check your content types at path `admin/structure/types`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with a [hook update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x). Within this hook update, you can run a [database query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7.x) or even better an [EntityFieldQuery](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7.x) to select all the nodes/node IDs from the database that have a specific field value or a specific word/set of words with a SQL LIKE operator. From there you can loop through all the nodes and delete them via [node_delete()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_delete/7.x).